# Python, capture OS output and send as a message in discord

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio

For a bot im making i want to be able to view the temperature of the pi running it (of course the command can only be used by a dev). My issue is that i cant seam to get the output of the terminal command. I know for a fact that the command half works, because I can see the correct output on the pi's screen, but the bot only posts a "0" to the chat.

Things i have tried:

```
async def cmd_temp(self, channel):
    proc = subprocess.Popen('/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp',
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    temperature = proc.stdout.read()
    await self.safe_send_message(channel, temperature)


async def cmd_temp(self, channel):
    await self.safe_send_message(channel,
        (os.system("/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp")))


async def cmd_temp(self, channel):
    temperature = os.system("/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp")
    await self.safe_send_message(channel, temperature)
```

Each of these does the same thing, posts a 0 in the chat, and the output on the screen of the pi. If anyone can help, i'd greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [asyncio.subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) module lets you deal with subprocesses in an asynchronous manner:

```
async def cmd_temp(self, channel):
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        '/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd', 
        'measure_temp', 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
    temperature = stdout.decode().strip()
    await self.safe_send_message(channel, temperature)
```

See more examples in the [asyncio user documentation](https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess.html).